# Why is init! still in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

In Swift 3, IUO (implicitly unwrapped optionals) were modified such that assigning an IUO to an identifier with no declared type would have the type inferred as `T?` instead of `T!`. This also applies to `init!`. Because of this, it seems that for most accounts, `init?` and `init!` are semantically the same considering you can do:

```
struct Thing {
    init?(v1: Void) {
        return nil
    }
    init!(v2: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}

var thing1: Thing! = Thing.init(v1: ())
var thing2: Thing? = Thing.init(v2: 2)
var thing3: Thing? = Thing.init(v1: ())
var thing4: Thing! = Thing.init(v2: 2)
```

Two reasons I can think of for keeping `init!` around are:

1. Improve readability by indicating an initializer really should not fail
2. Support Objective-C for unannotated (no `nullable`) initializers that may return nil or non-nil which still effectively become type inferred as optional (`T?`) in most scenarios of usage.

Edit: Comments have some use cases that do set `init?` and `init!` apart semantically. The same cases apply to any function that would returning a `T?` or `T!`.

New cases that are different from `init?`:

```
var thing5: Thing = Thing.init(v2: 2)
Thing.init(v2: 2).prop
```

For these, based on the proposal that changed behavior from Swift 2 to 3 (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md), it seems like the `thing5` case should have also applied (and would break existing code) such that you would instead do `var thing5: Thing = Thing.init(v2: 2)!`. The last case seems okay and legitimate, however.

Comment: You can do `let thing5: Thing = Thing(v2: 5)` with the IUO failable initialiser though, which you can't do with the 'strong optional' version (not that I would ever recommend actually defining a Swift IUO failable initialiser though).

Comment: Ah. Good point. Also, `Thing.init(v2: 2).property` would also fail.